# Redirect user based on his language and country using WPML

Tags: plugin-wpml, language, ip

I am using WPML as a languages solution in my blog (in my case it's English and Spanish)
I would like to know if there is a simple way of detecting where is a user coming from (which country.. I believe by IP) and redirect him immediately to either the Spanish site or the English site.
for instance: my site is **www.website.com** and the Spanish version is **www.website.com/es**
I want people from lets say Argentina (and more latin countries) to see **www.website.com/es**
and English spoken countries will see the regular English homepage as default.
Does someone have a solution?
Thanks a lot
Gil

Comment: http://html5demos.com/geo | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248404/about-geolocation-in-html-5 | I'm torn on whether to suggest closure. Just because WPML is involved, does this become on-topic? I feel it isn't, but I'm not sure enough to close vote.

Comment: @fischi gave the correct answer. Although this seems a good option, I would never use it on a site. Reason is that I like to give people the freedom instead of forcing a language on them. In your example all is fine, but take a non-Spanish speaker living in Spain or Latin America. That person most likely wants to see your site in English, not in Spanish, but as the IP address is from one of those countries, Spanish is forced upon him/her.

Comment: @Piet I like your reasoning there - but WPML offers the Redirect based on the Browser Language. I do not suppose that a lot of people use a Browser in a Language they don't speak. Also, you always have the possibility to switch back.

Comment: @fischi sorry, you are right, the redirect is on browser language, not on IP.

Comment: Maybe there is an htaccess solution or something.. I will also check with the WPML people. Thanks a lot @fischi

Answer (score 2):

WPML offers this feature.
You can set it in the `Languages` adminsection, at the option `Browser Language Redirect`.

Comment: Hi guys and thank you for your kind answers. @fischi - I found this option:   Always redirect visitors based on browser language (redirect to home page if translations are missing) and checked it.  It says that it goes by the browser's language and not country or IP.  Do u think it's a good solution? what if a guy in a latin country has English version browser? will he see the English or the Spanish version?  Thanks

Comment: @gilhamer yeah i think this is a good solution, as a visitor from a latin country does not certainly speak Spanish - the browser language gives you the best clue to the preferred language of the user.

Comment: +1 That is definitely *the best* solution. I am German and I live in Germany, but my OS and Browser language is English. I use google.com and not google.de. When on a new / friend's / other system and google.com redirects me to google.de it annoys the living crap out of me. Hence, I'd say, yes, best solution. | As an aside, if this is an inherent feature of WPML, I suppose it was a good decision not to vote to close.

Answer (score -1):

I would add leaving a clear way of switching to other languages in case the visitor wants to (showing language "flags" maybe), don't know if WMPL includes this function

Comment: Not to be rude, but your answer isn't very good and not even answers the question, which was about automatic redirecting based on language, for the future, take a look at [answer]